# How to change header image every page

Tags: php, jquery, image

I'm using Drupal 7. I have page.tpl.php files and 5 menu items. And i want, change header image every menu. Be 1 img.

İs is possible via jQuery or another way?

Comment: Are you saying that you've written own theme or changed an existing one?

Comment: Please try to explain what you are trying to do more clearly, it is hard to understand what you want at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to change header image every page request- like rotating banners.
Easiest way- change location of img in your HTML to a PHP script, like this:

```
<img src="myheader.php">
```

Then create myheader.php which will load image you want- each time different and serve it, like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$number = time() % 5;
readfile($number . '.png');
```

This will serve images 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png. If you have more images- change %5 to your value.
How does it work? It divides number of seconds since 01.01.1970 by 5 and returns reminder. So the reminder is always 0-4. So it serves images 0-4 + '.png'.
All your images must be PNG. If they are not- you need to alter "Content-type" header.